# Magento2 Guest Checkout page?

Tags: magento2, guest-checkout

We're integrating with **Magento2** and everything works good when we have customer logged in. As our client requested us to allow user to **`register/login`** only when checkout, we faced some problem:

1. We managed to call **`/V1/carts/`** and created the cart
2. We also managed to add items into guestcart by calling **`"/V1/carts/$QUOTE_ID/items"`**
3. But when we redirect user to **`"/checkout/cart"`** page, it show empty items on our cart. 
   **This works great when we have customer logged in**

May I know if there is a guest checkout URL which we should redirects guest to, by specifying the QUOTEID so system can retrieve the list of items?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea anyone? Why I can't find any documentation regarding this?  

I tried another way to use guest-carts:
a) I called /V1/guest-carts/ to get the cart key
b) Then, I called /V1/guest-carts/cart-key/items to store the item, and items are added with quote_id & item_id returned
c) but when I redirect to /checkout/cart/, same issue happened!! 

So where should I redirect user to? HELP!!